# JSX React variable returning "0" instead of component

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx

I have pure component with a variable that stores a conditional section of the component. When the section is supposed to show I get a "0" instead of the actual section:

```
export function MyComponent(props) {
    let section;

    if (props.showSection) {
        section = (
            <span>{ props.firstName } { props.lastName | ""}</span>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div> { props.children } { section } </div>
    )
}
```

Then later when I use it:

```
...
return (
    <div>
        <MyComponent showSection={ true } firstName="philip" lastName="johnson">
            My First Name is
        </MyComponent>
    </div>
)
...
```

results in:

"My first name is 0"

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because of that single pipe `|`.

That little pipe is turning it into a [bitwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7c_%28Bitwise_OR%29) operation.

Double pipe it and that will fix the problem.

```
...
section = (
            <span>{ props.firstName } { props.lastName || ""}</span>
        )
...
```

Comment: Unless someone else provides a better explanation, then I will mark the better one.